# how to have multiple SWF domain share the same workflow decider and activity code

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

We have a use case in SWF, where we want to segregate SWF workflow executions in different domains per calling clients. We want to reuse the workflow decider code and activity code across all domains without making duplicates. Has anyone tried this before ?

Comment: Are you planning on using Java and [AWS Flow Framework](https://aws.amazon.com/swf/details/flow/)? I believe that might change the answer.

Comment: yes kobi@, we are planning to use AWS Flow framework

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "code reuse". Workflows and activities are code, so you can package the reusable part into its own libraries and reuse them from multiple workflows.